# How do you add extra binaries to an android build?

Tags: java, android, build, android-source

I have some custom binaries that I would like to include in a custom build of android and I was trying to figure out where I need to place it and what make file I should edit so that when I build it, the binaries will automatically be placed in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [watch](http://marakana.com/s/video_tutorial_android_internals_building_a_custom_rom_pt_1_of_2,269/index.html) this video (the first and the second part). In these videos it's explained how to add different type of packages. Moreover, [here](http://www.aton.com/android-native-development-using-the-android-open-source-project/) is a link that will help you to build a native application for Android.